# Find $L(f)$ and the value of $U(f)$

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

> Let $ f : [0, 1] → \mathbb{R}$ be a function given by
> $$
>  f(x) =
> \begin{cases}
> x^2 ,  & \text{if $x$ is rational} \\
> 2x^2, & \text{if $x$ is irrational}
> \end{cases}$$
> Find $L(f)$ and write down the value of $U(f)$. Hence, show that $f$ is not Riemann integrable on $[0, 1]$.

Considering  the general partition $P=\{x_0,x_1,...,x_n\}$ of $[0,1]$ I got

$m_k=\inf\{f(x); x \in [x_{k-1},x_k]  \}=x^2_{k-1}$

$M_k=\sup\{f(x); x \in [x_{k-1},x_k]  \}=2x^2_{k}$

therefore

$$L(f;P)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}m_k \Delta x_k=\sum_{k=1}^{n} x^2_{k-1} \Delta x_k$$ and

$$U(f;P)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}M_k \Delta x_k=\sum_{k=1}^{n} 2x^2_{k} \Delta x_k$$

I know  $L(f)=\sup \{\space L(f;P); \text{P is partition of  } \space [0,1] \} $ and $U(f)=\inf \{ \space L(f;P); \text{P is partition of} \space [0,1] \} $

but I cannot go further, Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you use that $g(x) = x^2$ is integrable?

Comment: @MartinR Sorry  I didn't get it Can you explain it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $x\in[0,1]$, $x^2 \le x \le 1$ so
$$
m_{k} = \inf\left\{f(x)\ |\ x \in [x_{k-1}, x_{k}]\right\} = x_{k-1}^2
$$

Therefore,
$$
L(f, P) = \sum_{k=1}^{n}m_k\, \Delta x_{k} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} x_{k-1}^2\, \Delta x_{k}
$$

Consider the partition $P = \left\{0, \frac{1}{n}, \frac{2}{n}, \dots, 1\right\}$. Then
\begin{align}
L(f) &= \lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n} x_{k-1}^2\, \Delta x_{k} \\
&= \lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \left(\frac{k-1}{n}\right)^2\, \frac{1}{n} \\
&= \lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(k-1)^2}{n^3} \\
&= \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n^3} \sum_{k=1}^{n} (k-1)^2 \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(k^2-2k+1\right)\\
&= \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n^3} \left[\left(\frac{n}{6} + \frac{n^2}{2} + \frac{n^3}{3}\right) - \left(n^2+n\right) + n\right] \\
&= \frac{1}{3} \\
\end{align}

Similarly, $U(f) = \frac{2}{3}$.

Since $U(f) \neq L(f)$, $f$ is not Riemann integrable on $[0, 1]$.

---

EDIT:

**Definition:** Let $P = \left\{x_0 = a, x_1, \dots, x_n = b\right\}$ be a partition of $[a, b]$ and let $\Delta x_i = x_i − x_{i−1}$ for $1 \le i \le n$. Then the norm $||P||$ of $P$ is defined by
$$
||P|| = \text{max}\left\{\Delta x_i\ |\ 1 \le i \le n\right\}
$$

**Lemma:** Let $f:[a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function and $P$ be a partition of $[a, b]$, then
$$
L(f) = \lim_{||P||\to 0} L(f, P)
$$

**Proof:**

Given any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a partition $Q = \{y_0 = a, y_1, y_2, \dots, y_n = b\} \subseteq [a, b]$ such that
$$
L(f, Q) > L(f) - \frac{\epsilon}{2}
$$

Let $M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|f(x)| < M$,
$\eta = \text{min}\left\{\Delta y_i\ |\ 1 \le i \le n\right\}$ and
$\delta < \text{min}\left\{\eta, \frac{\epsilon}{4(n-1)M}\right\}$.

Then for any partition $P = \{x_0 = a, x_1, x_2, \dots, x_m = b\} \subseteq [a, b]$ such that $||P|| < \delta$,
\begin{align}
\left|L(f, P \cup Q) - L(f, P)\right| &\le 2(n-1)M\delta \\
&< \frac{\epsilon}{2}
\end{align}

Thus,
\begin{align}
L(f, P) &= \left[L(f, P) - L(f, P \cup Q)\right] + L(f, P \cup Q) \\ 
&> \left(-\frac{\epsilon}{2}\right) + L(f) - \frac{\epsilon}{2}
\end{align}
$\therefore ||P|| < \delta \,\Rightarrow\, L(f) - L(f, P) < \epsilon$

Comment: Use the fact that $x^2$ is always less thant $2x^2$ so that, in any interval, the lower sum uses $x^2$ while the upper sum uses $2x^2$.  You also need the facts that the set of all rational numbers between 0 and1 has Lesbesque measure 0 while the set of all irrational numbers between 0 and 1 has measure 1.

Comment: @user247327 I already tried it but I can't go further

Comment: You are using special partition in $[0,1]$ not a general partition

Comment: You are right in that this is a specific partition on $[0,1]$. However, since the width of the subinterval approaches $0$, the equality holds. The proof of this equality essentially requires us to show that Darboux integral (i.e. upper & lower sums) is equivalent to Riemann integral (i.e. Riemann sum), which probably is not the main objective of this question; however, if you are interested, you may refer to [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Riemann_integral).

Comment: Can you explain how did you say f is not rieman integral by using specific partition? IS there theorem ?

Comment: I have added an addendum to my answer. It gives us a way to find $L(f)$ without specifying any partition; rather, what matters is that the norm of the partition approach $0$. So the choice of $P = \{0, \frac{1}{n}, \frac{2}{n}, \dots, 1\}$ is good enough since $||P|| \to 0$ as $n\to 0$.

Comment: +1 especially for the part which shows that the upper integral is limit of upper sums as norm of partition tends to $0$. This is a key theorem which allows us to find upper Integral using specific types of partitions.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Can this theorem use to prove dirichlet function is not riemann integrable?

Comment: @puka: handling Dirichlet is simple and it does not require any deep results. Just note that every upper sum is $1$ and every lower sum is $0$ no matter what partition of $[0,1]$ is chosen. So the integral does not exist.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thank you. But I wanted to test $P=\{0,\frac{1}{n},\frac{2}{n},..,1\}$ so  I got $L(f,P_n)=0$ is not equal $U(f,P_n)=1$ therefore Can I say  It is not riemann integrable?

Comment: @puka: just one partition won't suffice. You need to analyze infinitely many partitions. The theorem in answer helps here. Choose equal spaced partitions like the one you have in comment and then take limit as $n\to\infty $. Then upper integral is 1 and lower integral is $0$. So not Riemann integrable.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thank you very much. very helpful. Do you know any book to refer further those things?

Comment: @puka: follow the book recommended by your professor and for everything else rely on mathse. I studied most of analysis from Apostol's *Mathematical Analysis*.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh thank you very much

Comment: Can you explain how you got the $2(n-1)$?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Can you explain how he got  $2(n−1)$?